# Where does bluetoothctl store command history?

Tags: command-history, bluetooth

There is nothing about command history in `man bluetoothctl`, `info bluetoothctl`, and `bluetoothctl --help`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Short answer

`bluetoothctl` stores command history in `~/.cache/.bluetoothctl_history`.

---

#### Long answer

*Disclaimer: long answer requires some understanding of programming language C.*

`bluetoothctl` is a command line tool which is shipped with [BlueZ – Bluetooth protocol stack for Linux](http://www.bluez.org/). If we look at the source code of BlueZ:

- [official Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/about/)
- [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/bluez/bluez)

we'll quickly realize that `bluetoothctl` is using the [GNU Readline library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) for its interactive shell. Per [Readline's  documentation](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html), function `write_history` can be used to write history into a file. If we just grep for name of this function in the BlueZ source code:

```
$ grep write_history -r
src/shared/shell.c:             write_history(data.history);
```

History of the commands in `bluetoothctl` is written into a file, whose name is held in the field `.history` of the `struct data`. Then, just grepping for accesses to this field, we'll find where it is initialized:

```c
static void rl_init_history(void)
{
        const char *name;
        char *dir;

        memset(data.history, 0, sizeof(data.history));

        name = strrchr(data.name, '/');
        if (!name)
                name = data.name;
        else
                name++;

        dir = getenv("XDG_CACHE_HOME");
        if (dir) {
                snprintf(data.history, sizeof(data.history), "%s/.%s_history",
                                                        dir, name);
                goto done;
        }

        dir = getenv("HOME");
        if (dir) {
                snprintf(data.history, sizeof(data.history),
                                "%s/.cache/.%s_history", dir, name);
                goto done;
        }

        dir = getenv("PWD");
        if (dir) {
                snprintf(data.history, sizeof(data.history), "%s/.%s_history",
                                                        dir, name);
                goto done;
        }

        return;

done:
        read_history(data.history);
        using_history();
        bt_shell_set_env("HISTORY", data.history);
}
```

Here, `XDG_CACHE_HOME` comes from [freedesktop.org spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html). The other environment variables are basic `$HOME` and `$PWD`. Field `data.name` is set up elsewhere:

```c
void bt_shell_init(int argc, char **argv, const struct bt_shell_opt *opt)
{
...
    data.name = strrchr(argv[0], '/');
    if (!data.name)
        data.name = strdup(argv[0]);
    else
        data.name = strdup(++data.name);
...
}
```

So variable `char *name` in the function `rl_init_history` will contain the string `bluetoothctl`, name of the executable file. See [description of `argv` in C](https://www.cprogrammingbasics.com/argv-and-argc/).

So in most desktop environments, which follow the freedesktop.org spec, command line tool `bluetoothctl` will store the history of commands in the file `~/.cache/.bluetoothctl_history`. If the environment variable `XDG_CACHE_HOME` is defined, then history of commands will be stored in `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/.bluetoothctl_history`.